# how to create a enum property inside a class with typescript?

Tags: typescript

```
enum TYPES{
   signin,
   signup
}

import {TYPES} from 'filename'

class A{
   _types : TYPES = TYPES; //typescript is throwing error
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class A{
   _types : typeof TYPES = TYPES;
}
```